# Bug restore brightness iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, brightness

I'm waiting for a way to be able to restore the brightness of the iphone when my app enter background. I know that bug existed, but does anyone know if was corrected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has any solution without usage of private methods.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7.0.3, no changes till this time.